# comparing the column of two text files

Tags: perl

i have some data of two text files like:

file1.txt:

```
contig postion      majorallele minorallele highqualty reliable defin highqualty 
Contig1         479 *   C   0   0   0   0
Contig1         617 T   A   0   0   0   0
Contig15    243 T   C   0   0   0   0
Contig15    471 T   C   0   0   0   0
```

file2.txt

```
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000476-044111330
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000477-044111331
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000478-044111332
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000479-044111333
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000480-044111334
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000481-044111335
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000482-044111336
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000242-018378247
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000243-018378248
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000244-018378249
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000245-018378250
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000468-018377016
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000469-018377017
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000470-018377018
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000471-018377019
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000472-018377020
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000473-018377021
```

what i want to do is compare first two columns of file1.txt with 1 and fifth column of file2.txt and return the output as:

```
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000479-044111333 * C   0   0   0   0
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000243-018378248 T    C   0   0   0   0
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000471-018377019 T    C   0   0   0   0
```

that is merge the matching lines from both files in the output.

Comment: I can see right now that column 5 in file2.txt does not match columns 1 and 2 in file1.txt. Though column 1 and 2 in file2.txt does contain the same text as in column 1 in file1.txt, and the number is col 2.1 is within the range of col 5.2.

Comment: You should also know that questions that ask for someone else to do all the work for free are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a bit simply using awk than in perl.

```
awk 'FNR==NR && NR!=1
{x=tolower($1);
y=$2;
$1=$2="";
a[x""y]=$0;
next
}{
b=$5;
gsub(/^0*/,"",b);
split(b,c,"-");
if($1$2c[1] in a)print $0,a[$1$2c[1]]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp1
contig postion      majorallele minorallele highqualty reliable defin highqualty 
Contig1         479 *   C   0   0   0   0
Contig1         617 T   A   0   0   0   0
Contig15    243 T   C   0   0   0   0
Contig15    471 T   C   0   0   0   0
>
> cat temp2
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000476-044111330
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000477-044111331
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000478-044111332
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000479-044111333
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000480-044111334
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000481-044111335
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000482-044111336
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000242-018378247
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000243-018378248
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000244-018378249
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000245-018378250
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000468-018377016
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000469-018377017
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000470-018377018
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000471-018377019
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000472-018377020
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000473-018377021
>
> nawk 'FNR==NR && NR!=1{x=tolower($1);y=$2;$1=$2="";a[x""y]=$0;next}{b=$5;gsub(/^0*/,"",b);split(b,c,"-");if($1$2c[1] in a)print $0,a[$1$2c[1]]}' temp1 temp2
contig 1 chromosome 0 000000479-044111333   * C 0 0 0 0
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000243-018378248   T C 0 0 0 0
contig 15 chromosome 3 000000471-018377019   T C 0 0 0 0
>
```

Comment: thanx for this. but i need it for windows perl. i am using active perl  version 5.10.1

Comment: i would be really grateful if you help it for windows environment.